# Send email issue

Tags: php

I am noob with php so pardon my ignorance. I have created php form and it is working fine except one thing. When i get my mail it says that its send from **nobody** , i have no idea how can i solve this issue so i am asking for little help! Thank you!!! 
Here's my code:

```
     <?php  

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {  

        if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {  
            $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
            if ($_POST['name'] == "") {  
                $errors .= 'Molimo unesite Vaše ispravno ime.';  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= '<p>Molimo unesite Vaše ime.</p>';  
        }  

        if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {  
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {  
                $errors .= "$email is <strong>NIJE</strong>  valjana email adresa.<br/><br/>";  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= '<p>Molimo unesite  email adresu.</p>';  
        }  




        if ($_POST['message'] != "") {  
            $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  


        }  

        if (!$errors) { 

            $mail_to = 'dejo.dekic@yahoo.com';  
            $subject = 'Kontakt';  
            $tema = 'Info';
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers  = 'Od: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n"; 
            $headers .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";  
            $headers .= "Poruka:\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n";  

            $user = $_POST['email'];
            $poruka ='Vaš kontakt je uspjesno zaprimljen! Odgovorit ću vam u najkraćem mogućem roku. Hvala! Molimo ne odgovarajte na ovu poruku. Ova poruka je automatska.';
            mail($mail_to, $subject, $headers, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;");  
            mail($user, $tema, $poruka, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;"); 

            echo "<div style='color:white;margin:0px auto;padding-top:20px;width:290px;background-color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'><p>Hvala Vam na kontaktu!</p></div>";

        } else {  
            echo '<div class="errors">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';  

        }  
    }  

?>
```

And this is how it looks in my yahoo mail:http://www.homepagepays.robertpeic.com/yahoo.png

Comment: why you are assinging the $_POST['name'] a filtered value?

Comment: Why are you using your `Content-Type` directly in your `mail()`? You would be better off declaring it in `$headers` right away. Plus, your `$headers  = 'Od: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n";` is missing a `dot` before `= 'Od: '`

Comment: The first $headers declaration does not need a `dot` before `=` e.g. `$headers =`, but is required for all other subsequently following `$headers .=`

Comment: Thx!! Fred i am new to php and i will modfy my script as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$from = 'yourdesiredemail@here.com';
$headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
```

Just need an addition to the header.

Comment: It works kinda,but only when I open my mail. On yahoo it still says its from nobody:(  Maybe its server problem?  But THX!

Answer (score 0):

After little  struggle i have managed to solve this with your help:) So i am posting a solution if someone had the same problem. Thx! Notice: ***$add_headers and inside mail function: -fmail@robertpeic.com*** Here my full code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {  

        if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {  
            $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
            if ($_POST['name'] == "") {  
                $errors .= 'Molimo unesite Vaše ispravno ime.';  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= '<p>Molimo unesite Vaše ime.</p>';  
        }  

        if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {  
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {  
                $errors .= "$email is <strong>NIJE</strong>  valjana email adresa.<br/><br/>";  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= '<p>Molimo unesite  email adresu.</p>';  
        }  




        if ($_POST['message'] != "") {  
            $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  


        }  

        if (!$errors) { 

            $mail_to = 'dejo.dekic@yahoo.com';  
            $subject = 'Kontakt';  
            $tema = 'Info';
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .=  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Od: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n"; 
            $headers .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";  
            $headers .= "Poruka:\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n"; 
            $add_headers = 'From: mail@robertpeic.com' . "\r\n". "Return-path: mail@robertpeic.com" . "\r\n";

            $user = $_POST['email'];
            $poruka ='Vaš kontakt je uspjesno zaprimljen! Odgovorit ću vam u najkraćem mogućem roku. Hvala! Molimo ne odgovarajte na ovu poruku. Ova poruka je automatska.';
            mail($mail_to, $subject, $headers, $add_headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com");  
            mail($user, $tema, $poruka, $add_headers, "-fmail@robertpeic.com"); 

            echo "<div style='color:white;margin:0px auto;padding-top:20px;width:290px;background-color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;'><p>Hvala Vam na kontaktu!</p></div>";

        } else {  
            echo '<div class="errors">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';  

        }  
    }  

?>
```

This is how it look's NOW in my yahoo mail: http://www.homepagepays.robertpeic.com/yahoo2.png